# Android studio compile finished with non-zero value 2

Tags: android, compilation

> Error:Execution failed for task ':myApp:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- project :pageIndicatorLib
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
+--- project :simplecropimagelib
+--- com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9
|    \--- cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
+--- com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration -> 5.6.1
+--- com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.7.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.7.0
|    |    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.7.0
|    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.7.0
|    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.7.0
|    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.7.0
+--- com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.+ -> 1.0.19
+--- de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0
\--- com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4

-----------------------------------Edit------------------------------------
dependencies {
compile project(':pageIndicatorLib')
compile project(':simplecropimagelib')
compile files('libs/AMap_Services_V2.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/Android_2DMap_V2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/Android_Location_V1.3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/UPPayAssistEx.jar')
compile files('libs/UPPayPluginEx.jar')
compile files('libs/alipaysdk.jar')
compile files('libs/alipaysecsdk.jar')
compile files('libs/alipayutdid.jar')
compile files('libs/libammsdk.jar')
compile files('libs/mina-core-2.0.7.jar')
compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar')
compile files('libs/umeng-analytics-v5.4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
compile('com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9')
compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration')
compile('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.7.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19')
compile('de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0')
compile('com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4')
```

}

Above is the error message and my Gradle dependency.

I have removed the duplicate dependencies in my gradle build file but still getting this error. I don't think I've reached the 65k method limit. What can I do now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, this will be the problem of duplicate dependency, upload your gradle file.

**Edit:**

As I can see,you have 2 umeng analytics lib, try remove one of them and build.

Comment: Now look, I've added my dependency part of gradle file

Answer (score 0):

You should check `Java` path and `SDK` path. Maybe you can find the error cause.
Also you should have it in `build.gradle(app)`,

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: My java path and SDK path  is correct, and I have above code in my build.gradle file. Interesting thing is my project can compile without error(even without a single warning), but this exit value thing just come out when I run my app on my device. Now I think Eclipse is better than AS.

Comment: No, in my opinion it is because of your device. Run the app on your real device.

Comment: I did run the app on my real device, not emulator. The problem is solved thanks to the answer of gone. It's just the problem of duplicate dependency. Thank you all for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have libraries and methods, then you can enable multi dex support by declaring it in the gradle config.

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```